# Skip the .xsd when searching

Tags: visual-studio, search, ide, xsd

We use the built in table adapter wizard in VS2005 to build a portion of our app, resulting in an enormous .xsd file being generated.

It's never interesting to have this .xsd included when searching through code, so I would like to be able to skip it when using Visual Studio **Find**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best solution is to switch from **Quick Find** to **Find In Files** which gives us the "Look at these file types:" option. Instead of one of the defaults:

```
*.vb;*.resx;*.xsd;*.wsdl;*.xml;*.htm;*.html;*.css
```

Set it to just:

```
*.vb;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find is a workaround: Download the free baregrep program and use it to search your source directory.  You can set baregrep to search only .vb files and even though it searches the designer files (which you probably do not want) you can see which source files you need to search individually.  Baregrep is a really fine search program, handy to have on your machine.